# Change the URL dynamically for "Add New Item" link using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

List is loaded with `?frame=1` appended in the URL.

http://site/Lists/ListName/AllItems.aspx?iframe=1

On clicking **Add New Item** link for the list, I need to load the new item form without `?iframe=1` in URL using javascript/jquery.

http://site/Lists/ListName/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=&IsDlg=1?&iframe=1

Currently trying using below code but not working. please suggest.

```
$(document).on("click","#idHomePageNewItem",function(){
    cururlmod="http://site/Lists/ListName/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=&IsDlg=1";
    $("#idHomePageNewItem").attr("href", cururlmod);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that you want to load a new URL on click ?

Try this.
when you click tag with id "idHomePageNewItem" it will load your link in "cururlmod".

```js
$("#idHomePageNewItem").on("click",function(){
    cururlmod="http://site/Lists/ListName/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=&IsDlg=1";
    window.location.href = cururlmod;
});
```

Comment: hi Cryptc_Slaughtr , tried this...but still it is opening with "&?iframe=1".

Comment: I need to open the form to add new items without "&?iframe=1" and with "&IsDlg=1" so that upper ribbon elements in the form is visible.Any ideas?